# Extjs : url in store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

here is my store

Gave the url : '/rest/helloworld/submit',

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['name', 'date', 'email'],
    pageSize: 10, // items per page
    proxy: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/rest/helloworld/submit',
        disableCaching: false,
        type: 'json',
        root: 'result',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
});
```

But as i can see in the console of browser.

request for url is like : Request URL:http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/proxy/json.js?_dc=1428776089867

Also i added disableCaching : false

but it still shows _dc=1428776089867

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ajax` proxy and the [`noCache`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-noCache) property:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    fields: ['name', 'date', 'email'],
    pageSize: 10, // items per page
    proxy: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/rest/helloworld/submit',
        noCache: false,
        type: 'ajax',
        root: 'result',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah it works 

,but it sending request like 

http://localhost:8080/rest/helloworld/submit?start=0&limit=10&page=1

so i need to receive start,limit ad page as parameter in function. right ?